# straightforward hcf question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

This shouldn't be difficult but I can't get it out..:

Let $c,d,N$ be integers with $\operatorname{hcf}(c,d,N) = 1$. Show that there exist $m, n ∈\mathbb Z$ with $\operatorname{hcf}(c+mN,d+nN) = 1$

Any help appreciated!

Comment: For all $\,n\in \Bbb Z\!:\,$ $(c,N,d+nN) = (c,N,d)=1,\,$ so $\,(c+mN,d+nN)=1$ for some $\,m\in \Bbb Z$ by the dupe. $\ \ $